# Python Regex to match space or open parentheses

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Within a larger text, my aim is to extract the following using regex:

1. a known number and letter combination (the letter can up upper or lowercase)
2. this combination can be followed by a space or an open parenthesis followed by a number or letter.

for example: the sample text is:

> blah blah blah 123K blah blah 123k blah blah 123K(1)(e) 123k(z)(1)

the required result is:

- 123K, 123k, 123K(1)(e), 123k(z)(1)

I have tried the following:

```
[ ]+123(K|k)+[ ]
```

which works for 123K and 123k

however for the parentheses I tried (which doesn't work):

```
[ ]+123(K|k)+([ ]|(?<=\().*?(?=\),))
```

any guidance in solving this would be appreciated.

I am using Python 3.6

***EDIT:***
I have managed to edit my regex to match a parentheses after "K|k", updated regex is:

```
[ ]+123(K|k)+([ ]|\(\w\))
```

Comment: there's a comma in your regex but not in the sample string

Comment: removing the comma doesn't make any difference unfortunately

Comment: First, a real-time regexp tester is highly helpful in these cases.  A quick google found this https://pythex.org/ but there are likely others.  Beyond that, your #2 doesn't really state what your requirements are here.  This all gets messy because for "space" you don't require a matching space, but for pren you do.  Plus it isn't clear if other combinations must also match like 123K(1)a or 123Kabc(1), etc.  Then as stated "123k a 1(2)b" might be something you want to match.  You need to get really clear what you want to match and your #2 as stated isn't that clear . . . at least to me.

Comment: @FrankMerrow I've been using https://regex101.com/ to test my regex. regarding point 2, just to clarify (ignoring the case from point 1 to simplify the explanation), I would expect the following combination: 123k or 123k(1) or 123k(e) or 123k(1)(e). I have been using a space as a demarcation point to end the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am setting the limit of search for consecutive open and close brackets from 0 to 2 after 123(k|K) based on your example.

**Code**

```
import re
m = re.findall('(123(k|K)(\(.\)){0,2})', 'blah blah blah 123K blah blah 123k blah blah 123K(1)(e) 123k(z)(1)')

result = [i[0] for i in m]
```

**Result**

```
['123K', '123k', '123K(1)(e)', '123k(z)(1)']
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is getting close to what you want?

```
123(k|K)(\([0-9a-zA-Z]?\)){0,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired matches, you could use a character class to match upper or lower case k like `[Kk]` or use `re.IGNORECASE`.

If you don't need the values in the capturing group for further processing, you could make the group non capturing `(?:`

To match any occurrences of an opening and closing parenthesis with a single word character in between you could capture the match in a group and repeat the group 0 or more times.

```
\b123[Kk](?:\(\w\))*
```

Explanation

- `\b123` Match 123 preceded by a word boundary to prevent it being part of a larger word
- `[Kk]` Match an upper or lowercase k
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\(\w\)` Match a word character between parenthesis
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pm2ZFl/1)

Example code

```
import re
regex = r"\b123k(?:\(\w\))*"
s = "blah blah blah 123K blah blah 123k blah blah 123K(1)(e) 123k(z)(1)"
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output

```
['123K', '123k', '123K(1)(e)', '123k(z)(1)']
```